# How can I return a generic class from a method?

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a method "get" that will return a class. But instead of a concrete class I want to be able to return any subclass of a certain concrete class. Here is the concrete case:

```scala
def get(): Class[Base] = {
    classOf[Base]
}
```

Now I want to turn this into a generic method, something like this:

```scala
def get[T <: Base](): Class[T] = {
    classOf[Derived]
}
```

How can I do this?

For completeness:

```scala
class Base
class Derived extends Base
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
def get(): Class[_ <: Base] = {
  classOf[Derived]
}
```